# JDBC Null Pointer Exception when Creating Table

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, nullpointerexception

When I run my program, there is a Null Pointer Exception associated with createCarMaker. I checked the DB connection and it seems all okay. May I please have some help troubleshooting.

```
CarDBHelper(){
    try 
    { 
        //Establish a driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 

        //Connect to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        System.err.println("Unable to load MySQL driver."); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 

}
/**
 * Creates the tables carMaker and Vehicle with various parameters.
 * 
 */
public void createTables(){
    try {
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String createcarMaker = "CREATE TABLE carMaker " +
            "(makerID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
            " makerName VARCHAR(50), " +
            " PRIMARY KEY ( makerID ))";

        statement.executeUpdate(createcarMaker);

        String createVehicle = "CREATE TABLE Vehicle " +
            "(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
            " year INT, " +
            " make INT, " +
            " model VARCHAR(50), " +
            " FOREIGN KEY (make) REFERENCES carMaker(makerID)," +
            " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

        statement.executeUpdate(createVehicle);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong declared variable of Statement in 'statement' and 'stmt'.

Furthermore please put the stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an undeclared variable.  You declare:

```
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
```

But then reference:

```
statement.executeUpdate(createcarMaker);
```

stmt != statement.